# MVC 4 Web API 2 ajax call all parameters optional

Tags: android, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I realy want your option.
We update a .net MVC 3 project to MVC 4 with web api 2, this a web service.
The ajax calls is from android machines with the Devextreme/Phonegap.

After the update the web service when i call login from android i get 
"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://www.whatever.gr/MVCService/Actions/Login'"

I want to set the route so that all methods of the MVC service can have parameters optional.
I can't get this work..

We can't change the source on the android app,and ajax call is the code below

```
function doLogin(username, password, callback) {
    loading(true);

    var dataStr = "uid=" + uid + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    var success = false;
    var token = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: registrationServiceUrl + 'Login',
        data: dataStr,
        beforeSend: function () {
            //alert("registration no: " + registrationid);
        },
        success: function (retval) {
            if (retval.indexOf('SUCCESS') == 0) {
                success = true;
                token = retval.substring(8);
                //setTokenToSettings(token); 
            } else {
                success = false;
            };
            callback(success, token);
            loading(false);

        },
        error: function (retval) {
            callback(success, token);
            loading(false);

        }
    });
}
```

The route in MVC is

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                // Web API configuration and services

                // Web API routes
                //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "ActionApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
```

When i hit like below with parameters in a browser i have a response 
'http://www.whatever.gr/MVCService/Actions/Login?param1=1&param=2&param3=3'.

I want to have the behavior, when to hit 'http://www.whatever.gr/MVCService/Actions/Login'
or
'http://www.whatever.gr/MVCService/Actions/Login?param1=1&param=2&param3=3&invalidParamName=x'.

And the web service method to be trigger with empty parameters values.

But without setting optional parameters in the method

```
public string Login(string pamar1 = "",string param2 = "", string param3 = "")
```

With MVC 3 this was working fine as I explained before.

Thanks in advance and for your time.

Comment: Hi, I don't think it's anything to do with your client application. I had the same problem a while ago. Please take a look at this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093603/simple-post-to-web-api/19094245#19094245 and also see the reason behind it in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424493/why-does-asp-net-web-api-allow-only-one-parameter-for-post-method

Comment: I have tried [HttpGet(), HttpPost()]
        public JsonResult<string> Login([FromBody]string uid, [FromBody]string username, [FromBody]string password) but i get An error has occurred

Comment: I think this is the ajax call data: dataStr  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: registrationServiceUrl + 'Login',
        data: dataStr,
but how this works on MVC 3??

Comment: You cannot use more than one [FormBody] attribute

Answer (score 0):

In Web API, it's very simple to remember how parameter binding is happening.

- if you `POST` simple types, Web API tries to bind it from the URL
- if you `POST` complex type, Web API tries to bind it from the body of
  the request (this uses a media-type formatter).

This asp.net page explains it all. 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api