# How to pass multiple json array to controller from ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two json array. I'm trying to send these json array to my controller. When i want to send one of them, everything is fine but i couldnt't send second one. How can i fix it ?

**Post function from view**

```js
function HobiIlgiAlanKaydetGuncelle() {

    var hobiler = $('#Hobiler').val(); // Json array of object
    var ilgiAlanlar = $('#IlgiAlan').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Kullanici/HobiVeIlgiAlanlariniKaydetGuncelle",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {hobiler : hobiler,ilgiAlanlar : ilgiAlanlar},
        success: function (response) { }

    });
}
```

**Controller**

```c#
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> HobiVeIlgiAlanlariniKaydetGuncelle([FromBody] List<HobilerVM> hobiler, List<IlgiAlanlarVM> ilgiAlanlar)
{
   //When I put second parameter, both of them comes with null    
}
```

**HobilerVM**

```c#
public class HobilerVM
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

**IlgiAlanVM**

```c#
public class IlgiAlanVM
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC3 & JSON.stringify() ModelBinding returns null model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597892/mvc3-json-stringify-modelbinding-returns-null-model) `JSON.stringify({hobiler : hobiler,ilgiAlanlar : ilgiAlanlar})` should do it...

Comment: I think this is useful for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407458/webapi-multiple-put-post-parameters

Comment: parameters have already stringify by tagify library.
I can send without stringify when i send only hobiler.

Comment: @Trinity: Which version of MVC are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the following line:

```
data: {hobiler : hobiler,ilgiAlanlar : ilgiAlanlar}
```

This is an object in javascript. The equivalent in c# should be:

```
public class MyData {
    public List<HobilerVM> hobiler;
    public List<IlgiAlanlarVM> ilgiAlanlar;
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> HobiVeIlgiAlanlariniKaydetGuncelle([FromBody] MyData data)
    {
       //When i put second parameter, both of them comes with null    
    }
```

For more information, check [Why does ASP.NET Web API allow only one parameter for POST method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424493/why-does-asp-net-web-api-allow-only-one-parameter-for-post-method)

Comment: I did yours but still comes with null.

Comment: Also not sending JSON when specifiying it as contentType

Comment: What did you mean ?

Comment: Is all the data object null or just the second property?

Comment: When i put second parameter all data object comes with null. But there is no problem with when i send single parameter such as hobiler.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras: If @Trinity is using MVC 5 (or less), `[FromBody]` is not allowed in a MVC Controller, only in an API Controller.

Comment: Make sure that ilgiAlanlar is a serializable array before you assign it in javascript.

Comment: My guess is that it's not an array and thus the entire serialization fails

Answer (score 0):

> Web API doesn’t allow you to pass multiple complex objects in the
> method signature of a Web API controller method — you can post only a
> single value to a Web API action method. This value in turn can even
> be a complex object. It is possible to pass multiple values though on
> a POST or a PUT operation by mapping one parameter to the actual
> content and the remaining ones via query strings.*Reference:* [How to pass multiple parameters to Web API controller methods](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3136743/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-web-api-controller-methods.html) and [How WebAPI does Parameter Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding)

**Solution**

```
public class ComplexObject {
   property List<HobilerVM> Hobiler { get; set; }
   property List<IlgiAlanlarVM> IlgiAlanlar { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> HobiVeIlgiAlanlariniKaydetGuncelle([FromBody] ComplexObject data)
{
 //When i put second parameter, both of them comes with null    
}
```

Happy coding, cheers!

Comment: still comes with null.

Comment: data: {hobiler : hobiler,ilgiAlanlar : ilgiAlanlar} change this to data: {hobiler : JSON.stringify(hobiler),ilgiAlanlar : JSON.stringify(ilgiAlanlar)}

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine for me except for some things.

First your second parameter has a different ViewModel on what you have posted on your code:

```
public class IlgiAlanVM
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string value { get; set; }
}
```

But on your parameter, you are using a different ViewModel:

```
([FromBody] List<HobilerVM> hobiler, List<IlgiAlanlarVM> ilgiAlanlar)
```

As you can see here, `IlgiAlanVM` is different on `List<IlgiAlanlarVM>`

Second, I just I used the same code but without the `[FromBody]`. So that would be:

```
//I already edited your List of Model here on the second parameter from IlgiAlanVM to IlgiAlanlarVM
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> HobiVeIlgiAlanlariniKaydetGuncelle
                          (List<HobilerVM> hobiler, List<IlgiAlanlarVM> ilgiAlanlar)
```

Lastly, I just make sure it's an array of objects to make sure it will bind nicely on your list of models:

```
        var hobiler = [{
            id: 1,
            value: 'My Value'
        }];
            
        var ilgiAlanlar = [{
            id: 1,
            value: 'MyValue'
        }];

       $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HobiVeIlgiAlanlariniKaydetGuncelle", "Kullanici")',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ hobiler : hobiler, ilgiAlanlar : ilgiAlanlar }),
            success: function (response) { }
        });
```